# What's the difference in the glow color of the message ratings?

Tags: elden-ring

When examing message ratings some appear to have a white glow and some have a golden glow which is a bit bigger then the white ones.

What's the difference between these 2 message ratings?

White glow:
[image]

Golden glow:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It represents the high-rated messages. At the bottom right corner of the message window there is an appraisal count, if it reaches some point it will glow. I'm not sure of the exact number.

As far as I know (and if it's the same as Demon's / Dark Souls and Bloodborne), there is no difference outside of that.

Comment: If it is the same as Dark Souls, people **love** to troll with these. I remember there being one that was highly upvoted and remained for months only for it to trick people into thinking there was secret passage

Comment: @Wondercricket Yeah, I've seen that kind of message in Elden Ring too. I actually enjoy them... I upvote that kind of message just to trick other players! :P